# Passing data to another page for bookmarking function

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, session-state

I have 1 gridview look like this:
[image]

Anytime user click on Bookmark button, I want to send the data in ProgramID column of that row to the List and pass it to second gridview in another page.But my second gridview doesn't display any data. What am I doing wrong?
This is my code for Bookmark button:

```
protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Button b = (Button)sender;      
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
    var ProgramID = row.FindControl("lblProgramID") as Label;
    string stringProgramID = ProgramID.Text;
    List<string> bookmarkPrograms = new List<string>();
    bookmarkPrograms.Add(stringProgramID);       
    Session["BookmarkProgram"] = bookmarkPrograms;        


}
```

And here is the code in Bookmark page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> bookMarkPrograms = (List<string>)Session["BookMarkPrograms"];

    GridView1.DataSource = bookMarkPrograms;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Session name you provided doesnot match i.e.
Session["BookmarkProgram"]

Comment: Yes, you're right. There are some typos in my code. But I want to allow user can make many bookmarks as they want.  Do you have any ideas for that???